# How to report confidence intervals for an interaction?

Tags: anova, confidence-interval, repeated-measures, f-test

I have a significant interaction in a repeated measures ANOVA. Two groups in my data are significantly different from one another. In order to report the overall confidence intervals, when I report the $F$-test statistic for the interaction, do I report the lower and upper confidence intervals that encompass the entire range of data?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're looking for. Please specify the design of the study in more detail. Are there comparisons that are more central than others? You say two groups are different but that seems like a non sequitor in the question. If it's important please explain how.